# How to infer a property depending on a comparison between two (transitive) properties on two individuals?

Tags: owl, ontology, inference, rdfs, swrl

I am modeling an ontology that shall be used to decide whether a person (a legal subject) is legally capable of accepting a contract. To do so, I model the contract itself, the jurisdiction it is under, the age of full legal capacity in a jurisdiction, and the legal subject.

One (simplifeid) example is this:

```xml
    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Jurisdiction"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#LegalStandard">
        <rdfs:comment>A legal standard, or contract</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#LegalSubject"/>

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#jurisdiction">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topObjectProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource=#LegalStandard"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Jurisdiction"/>
        <rdfs:comment>Jurisdiction this legal standard falsl under</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#livesIn">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topObjectProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource=#LegalSubject"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Jurisdiction"/>
        <rdfs:comment>Jurisdiction this legal subject lives in</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#legalAge">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topDataProperty"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Jurisdiction"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger"/>
        <rdfs:comment>Age at which a person reaches the age of majority in a jurisdiction</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#age">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topDataProperty"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#LegalSubject"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger"/>
        <rdfs:comment>Current age of an individual person</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="#Germany">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Jurisdiction"/>
        <ex:legalAge rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">18</ex:legalAge>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="#Terms">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#LegalStandard"/>
        <ex:jurisdiction rdf:resource="#Germany"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="#Fritzchen">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#LegalSubject"/>
        <ex:age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">25</ex:age>
        <ex:livesIn rdf:resource="#Germany"/>
    </owl>
```

In this model, I know that:

- The `Terms` are under the jurisdiction of `Germany`
- The `legalAge` in `Germany` is `18`
- The legal subject `Fritzchen` is 25 years old
- The legal subject `Fritzchen` lives in `Germany`

How do I ask whether `Fritzchen` is old enough to accept the terms of the contract?

I could, of course, re-model and make a class `PersonCapableOfAcceptingTerms`, but let's assume this is not feasible because the ontology will ultimately grow very huge.

My current tendency is that I will need SWRL for this, and if this is the case, I'd be happy about an example of how to do this with SWRL.

Comment: *"In this model, I know that the Terms are under the jurisdiction of Germany"* - how? I can only see `EU` as jurisdiction.

Comment: Moreover, there is no connection of `Fritzchen` and `Germany` - so how would you relate both individuals?

Comment: From my point of view, there are facts missing, but if you don't care about where `Fritzchen` lives, and where `Terms` holds, then all you have is the legal age of `Germany` and the age of `Fritzchen`, right? In that case the SWRL rule would be trival - but I still don'T think this is what you would want: `legalAge(?J, ?LA), age(?P, ?A), swrlb:greaterThan(?A, ?LA) -> PersonCapableOfAcceptingTerms(?P)` - you see, where is the fact that person `?P` is in jurisdiction `J`? Such that we can add another atom like `livesIn(?P, ?J)` to the rule. It's not in your data so far

Comment: @UninformedUser Oh sorry, I missed some important properties when reducing my ontology to a minimal example. Corrected!

So, your last comment implies that SWRL is indeed the way to go. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: is there also some relation between Germany and EU? In the meantime, you can try an  SWRL rule like `Jurisdiction(?J), LegalStandard(?S), jurisdiction(?S, ?J), legalAge(?J, ?LA), LegalSubject(?P), livesIn(?P, ?J), age(?P, ?A), swrlb:greaterThanOrEqual(?A, ?LA) -> isCapableOfAccepting(?P, ?S)` - you can see, I used an object property for the conclusion, because in the end you might want to relate a particular person to a particual legal standard, right? I hope, you get the idea with the SWRL rule?

Comment: @UninformedUser Yes, there is a relation between `Germaby` and `EU`, but it is not relevant here, and I simplified this above now.